# Fields are missing when I `pip show` my Python package

Tags: python, pip, setuptools, pypi, python-packaging

I recently uploaded my first Python package to PyPI. The relevant parts of `pyproject.toml` are defined as follows (full file available [here](https://github.com/jakelevi1996/jutility/blob/main/pyproject.toml)):

```
[build-system]
requires = ["setuptools>=61.0"]
build-backend = "setuptools.build_meta"

[project]
name = "jutility"
version = "0.0.4"
license = {text = "MIT License"}
authors = [
    {name = "Jake Levi", email = "jakelevi@hotmail.co.uk"},
]

# ...

[project.urls]
homepage = "https://github.com/jakelevi1996/jutility"
```

After installing this package with the command `python3 -m pip install -U jutility`, I run the command `python3 -m pip show jutility`, and get the following output:

```
Name: jutility
Version: 0.0.4
Summary: Collection of Python utilities intended to be useful for machine learning research and experiments
Home-page: 
Author: 
Author-email: Jake Levi <jakelevi@hotmail.co.uk>
License: MIT License
Location: /usr/local/lib/python3.10/dist-packages
Requires: matplotlib, numpy, Pillow
Required-by:
```

Notably, the `Home-page` and `Author` fields are empty in the output from `pip show`, although they seem to be defined in `pyproject.toml`.

How should I change `pyproject.toml` to make these fields display properly in the `pip show` output?

Version-wise, I built and uploaded these packages to PyPI on my Windows 10 PC with Python 3.7.6, but I also tried downloading and installing this package and displaying the `pip show` output from a Google Colab notebook with Python 3.10.11. The package works completely as expected in the Colab notebook, but I get the same `pip show` output with empty `Home-page` and `Author` fields. I'd just like to know what I need to change in order to get these fields to display properly.

Comment: Using setup.cfg did fix the homepage issue, still not showing author in mine too. https://github.com/RaSan147/pyrobox/blob/main/setup.cfg

Comment: The `pyproject.toml` files for [`numpy`](https://github.com/numpy/numpy/blob/main/pyproject.toml), [`matplotlib`](https://github.com/matplotlib/matplotlib/blob/main/pyproject.toml), and [`pytest`](https://github.com/pytest-dev/pytest/blob/main/pyproject.toml) all don't define `authors` or `homepage` yet have valid values for these fields in `pip show`, which seems unusual

Comment: Thank you @RatulHasan , this is useful - I'll have to learn more about `setup.cfg` files, I haven't used them before but it seems that they duplicate a lot of the information that I thought was supposed to go into `pyproject.toml`

Comment: Ah found it, in the setup.cfg, use author instead of authors. This should show author name

Comment: Check this page for more info: https://towardsdatascience.com/setuptools-python-571e7d5500f2

Comment: Thanks again @RatulHasan , problem now solved (see answer below)

Answer (score 1):

I fixed the issue by deleting all but the first 3 lines of `pyproject.toml`, so that `pyproject.toml` looks like this:

```
[build-system]
requires = ["setuptools>=61.0"]
build-backend = "setuptools.build_meta"
```

I then added the following configuration to `setup.cfg` (thank you to [@Ratul Hasan](https://stackoverflow.com/users/11071949/ratul-hasan) for the suggestion):

```
[metadata]
name = jutility
version = 0.0.8
author = Jake Levi
author_email = jakelevi@hotmail.co.uk
description = Collection of Python utilities intended to be useful for machine learning research and experiments
long_description = file: README.md
long_description_content_type = text/markdown
license = MIT License
license_files = LICENSE
url = https://github.com/jakelevi1996/jutility
project_urls =
    Documentation   = https://github.com/jakelevi1996/jutility
    Source Code     = https://github.com/jakelevi1996/jutility
    Bug Tracker     = https://github.com/jakelevi1996/jutility/issues

[options]
python_requires = >=3.7
install_requires =
    matplotlib>=3.5.3
    numpy>=1.21.6
    Pillow>=9.5.0
```

I now get the following output from `python3 -m pip show jutility`, as desired:

```
Name: jutility
Version: 0.0.8
Summary: Collection of Python utilities intended to be useful for machine learning research and experiments
Home-page: https://github.com/jakelevi1996/jutility
Author: Jake Levi
Author-email: jakelevi@hotmail.co.uk
License: MIT License
Location: /usr/local/lib/python3.10/dist-packages
Requires: matplotlib, numpy, Pillow
Required-by:
```

More information on `setup.cfg` files is given on the page [Configuring setuptools using `setup.cfg` files](https://setuptools.pypa.io/en/latest/userguide/declarative_config.html). It remains to be seen why `setup.cfg` files are not mentioned in [the Packaging Python Projects tutorial](https://packaging.python.org/en/latest/tutorials/packaging-projects/), but this is a question for someone else.

Comment: If I were you I would place as much metadata as possible in `pyproject.toml` because it has a standard specification, so it is better for interoperability with the rest of the Python packaging ecosystem. But I would still keep a `setup.cfg` file for things that are not standardized which includes the `url`/`Home-Page` field (as well as `license_files`) and for things that are specific to *setuptools*. Here is for example how I handled the migration to `pyproject.toml` for one of my projects: https://github.com/sinoroc/deptree/commit/ee74908aa08c4ee58ebf8bf2c58721473675384c